# Form or div for conditionally editable content

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs

This is more of a "best practice" question: I have a one-page website and for the admin I want to make the page editable. I am using angularjs + nodejs and once the admin is logged in I am rendering the page with input fields afters each paragraph and connecting them through my controllers.

Now my question is: should I use `form`s to display the content and hide/not render the submit button with the edit fields if the user is not logged in as admin or I should use `div/p` tags to enclose my content and add a simple button (conditioned by log-in state as well as the input fields) and fire an ajax call on `ng-click`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use 2 different layouts/views/directives, not to messed up presentation

Comment: But this would mean that I duplicate significant amount of code. I want to give the admin a snapshot of his modifications.

Comment: actually it depends on how many elements with different "state" do you have. Sometimes it's better to have duplication and have 2 clear layouts instead of one messy.

Comment: I have 3 sections that composed of 3-4 elements. I think code duplication might be an overkill in my case, but I see your point. +1